# WinRT embedded assets can only have known/specific file extensions?

Tags: windows-runtime, uri, assets

In developing a WinRT 8.1 app, I think that the Uri has to be only of known file extensions? Is that correct? For example, the following snippet will cause an exception on the `GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync` call even if this file exists as shown:

```cs
Uri uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/lake800x600.flanker");
StorageFile file = await 
    StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri).AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

However, if I change the file extension and the URI to '.dat' or '.txt' it works fine. Is this a known issue? Why can't I refer to and use files of any extension?

Comment: Update, .dat doesn't work, I thought it did, but .txt works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure your files are marked as content so they are included in the appx package.

Typical data file types such as .txt and .jpg will default to content, but you'll need to set it explicitly for other file types.

Compare a text file:
[image: Txt file marked as content]

And a .dat file:
[image: Dat file not marked as content]

You can confirm by creating a package (Store.Create app packages...), renaming the .appx to .zip, and opening it to see the files. You can also check the Appx folder created in your app's  bin\Debug\Appx directory when you deploy and run from Visual Studio

Comment: Thanks, you nailed the problem.